# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ḱ (U+1E31)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: unicode

I'm having this error while compiling. I do not know how to Declare this character in order to make it visibile so I can delete it.

Comment: I discovered that the problem is in my bibliography, when i do not print it I have no error. Hope this can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you type `h` to the error prompt it tells you:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ḱ (U+1E31)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.5 ḱ
       
? h
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

adding

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1E31}{\'k}
```

To your document allows it to run without error.

Comment: Since this character is used in transliteration of Macedonian, it might make sense to add it to `utf8enc.dfu`. The other Macedonian specific character is ǵ, that's already included.

Comment: @egreg I was wondering myself if we should do that, or perhaps the whole extended latin block, but maybe that's bigger than needed. upper and lowercase K ?

Comment: Several characters on the extended Latin blocks are there for completeness, I guess. I believe that characters used in Romanizations should be added to `utf8enc.dfu`. Maybe not complex things such as pinyin, for which there are specialized packages, but mappings alphabet to alphabet are simpler.

Comment: @egreg do you have a list?

Comment: I guess that we have a fairly complete coverage for Cyrillic European languages; I sent a list to the team.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to replace your `fontenc` and `inputenc` declarations with `\usepackage{fontspec}`, and compile in LuaTeX or XeTeX. This will use Unicode natively. It cuts the Gordian knot of problems caused by TeX starting out as 8-bit software.

However, it is possible that your font does not contain this character.  The legacy behavior of TeX is to silently ignore this error if it happens and leave blank spaces in your document.  To turn this into an error, add `\tracinglostchars=3`  near the top of your document.

You would actually fix the missing character by defining the code to render it with `newunicodechar`, or by changing fonts.